# How to return values which are produced from a for loop

Tags: java

I have a function which takes in some values, does some maths and then produces a set of type double values at the end. This being a function I have returned my value but it only returns 1 value and not all the values which are calculated within the for loop. What do I have to do so that my function returns all the values from within the for loop? If I stored the values inside an array, how would I be able to access them and use them later? These for loop values are going to be plotted on a graph so I need more than 1 value to plot.

Comment: Why don't you read at first about some basic data structures like array and list? This is a really-really simple question.

Answer (score 3):

You can instantiate your array outside of the loop which can be populated as the loop iterates

```
List<Double> plotPoints = new ArrayList<Double>;
for(...){
    plotPoints.add(...);
}
return plotPoints;
```

Since you are working on a graph, you might prefer to use a Map so you can align the x axis (the key) with the y axis (the value)